# Determining macro expansion for VarDecl in clang

Tags: c++, c, clang, oclint

I'm a beginner to C++, attempting to lint Objective-C code with clang. I understand that macros are first expanded before nodes and properties are visited with AST.

I have a macro named `NIL_CHECK`, which is used in numerous files. While performing the lint, I would like to skip the variable declaration of the line where this macro is expanded/used.

For instance, the first line in this example should be linted, while the second line needs to be skipped such that false positives are not thrown when there's a macro expansion:

```
// Must be checked
NSDictionary *playerParams = @{ @"videoId" : videoId, @"playerVars" : playerVars }; 

// Must be skipped since there's a macro
PlayerProfile *const playerProfile = [[PlayerProfile alloc] initWithData:NIL_CHECK(playerParams)];
```

Here is the `VisitVarDecl` visitor method, which traverses through each variable declaration to perform appropriate lint checks:

```
    bool VisitVarDecl(VarDecl *node) {
        if (isCollectionType(node -> getType()) && !hasTypeArguments(node -> getType())) {
            addViolation(node, this, description(node -> getNameAsString()));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

How can I determine macros and skip such variable declarations?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56513459/5520012) is a nice answer by Valeriy, I think it covers what you want to achieve.

To summarise:
You want to find the string `NIL_CHECK` inside a VarDecl, which has already been expanded when you visit the AST. The original text in your source code can be obtained with the help of `Lexer`. You can use the location of the full varDecl expr or only the macro-contained part. Then the macro name can be detected from the string returned by `getSourceText` of the Lexer .